# R way to create dataframe from a dataframe columns

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

Looking for a way in R to create a data-frame from another data-frame where the values of Col A act as indices and each unique values in Col B become new columns in the new data-frame with values of Col C being the values in the new column.

Data-frame 1:

| Col A | Col B | Col C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2011 | 1 |
| B | 2012 | 2 |
| C | 2013 | 3 |
| D | 2011 | 4 |
| E | 2012 | 5 |
| D | 2013 | 6 |
| A | 2013 | 7 |

Result:

| Col A | 2011 | 2012 | 2013 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0 | 7 |
| B | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| C | 0 | 0 | 3 |
| D | 4 | 0 | 6 |
| E | 0 | 0 | 5 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution.

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = Col.A,
    names_from = Col.B,
    values_from = Col.C,
    values_fill = 0L
  )
## A tibble: 5 x 4
#  Col.A `2011` `2012` `2013`
#  <chr>  <int>  <int>  <int>
#1 A          1      0      7
#2 B          0      2      0
#3 C          0      0      3
#4 D          4      0      6
#5 E          0      5      0
```

**Data**

```
df1 <-
structure(list(Col.A = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "D", "A"), 
Col.B = c(2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2013L), 
Col.C = 1:7), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a base R option using `reshape`

```
reshape(
  df,
  direction = "wide",
  idvar = "ColA",
  timevar = "ColB"
)
```

which gives

```
  ColA ColC.2011 ColC.2012 ColC.2013
1    A         1        NA         7
2    B        NA         2        NA
3    C        NA        NA         3
4    D         4        NA         6
5    E        NA         5        NA
```

---

A `data.table` option with `dcast`

```
> dcast(setDT(df),ColA~ColB, value.var = "ColC")
   ColA 2011 2012 2013
1:    A    1   NA    7
2:    B   NA    2   NA
3:    C   NA   NA    3
4:    D    4   NA    6
5:    E   NA    5   NA
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(ColA = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "D", "A"), ColB = c(2011L, 
2012L, 2013L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2013L), ColC = 1:7), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `xtabs` from `base R`

```
xtabs(Col.C ~ Col.A + Col.B, df1)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Col.A = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "D", "A"), 
    Col.B = c(2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2013L
    ), Col.C = 1:7), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```